# compiling multiple-source-file programs c++ using visual studio devolopers command prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, compiler-construction, linker

i have three files one is main.cpp the other one is GradeBook.h and GradeBook.cpp*
GradeBook.h is the public interface and GradeBook.cpp is GradeBook member-function definitions. This file contains implementations of the member functions prototyped in GradeBook.h.

How do i link and compile these files and be **brief** because i am learning c++  right until now i can compile c++ files using cl\EHsc command but after making three files i cant link them and compile please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will get details here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

For more compiler options you can check link below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve the answer of this post, the best answer can be found in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx) in the section "Next Steps". The correct way to compile it would be to write:

- "cl \EHsc main.cpp GradeBook.cpp"

In order to compile a program that has multiple source code files, enter them all on the command line.